# Correct way of providing children into Formik select field

Tags: reactjs, formik

I wanted to build multi-step form with state preservation and thankfully I've found number of tutorials for that. However, once I've started doing some modifications and adjustments I got a bit confused why it's not working.
I wanted to add select into form/basic.js but for some reason I'm getting error:

> input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use
> `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
> in input (created by Field)

Additionally I'm using React Router to retain data. That's the code of a form:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Field } from "formik";

class BasicPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Field type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Field type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Field type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Field name="country" as="select">
            <option value="france">France</option>
            <option value="greece">Greece</option>
            <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
          </Field>
        </div>
        <Link to="/form/location" className="next">Next</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BasicPage;
```

Whole codesandbox is here - https://codesandbox.io/s/tmp-forked-dv66l . Error can be seen in "Wizard" page.

Comment: i am not getting error in the code. I do not see select tag in the code either.

Comment: @NileshPatel thanks for pointing that out. I must have forgot to update after some tests. It's working (I mean error is present) now.

Comment: Router doesn't want the way you think it does, apparently : https://codesandbox.io/s/tmp-forked-dv66l?file=/src/form.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formik introduced the `<Field as>` in version **2**, and your using version **0.11.11**.

Try bumping the version to 2.2.5, and your example should work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/tmp-forked-vsz2b?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Simple solutions are the best!